# What are the addresses of r10 and r20 in this assembly code?

Tags: assembly, avr

When I look at this AVR assembly code with its equivalent (partially completed) address and binaries on I cannot figure out which registers are supposed to be r10 and r20. What I can figure out is, at least I believe, that registers X and Y are $004A and $004B respectively

[image: Assembly code]

Comment: Please do NOT post pictures of text, instead, copy the text and paste it into your question, with `\`\`\`` (backticks) above the first line and after the last so it formats as fixed-text (or you can indent all by 4-spaces). Your text would take roughly 300 bytes of storage. Instead you image requires `72.24 KB (73,969 bytes)` of storage.

Comment: I am so sorry, thank you for informing me

Comment: To reiterate on David's comment, could you edit your question to include the text? It would help others to give you a targeted answer and to actually reproduce your issue.

Comment: On AVR microcontrollers, registers r0-r31 correspond to addresses 0-31 (decimal). "X" is the combination of r26 and r27 (a 16-bit value). "Y" the combination of r28 and r29 and "Z" the combination of r30 and r31. "X" may contain the value $4A, however, the address of "X" is 26 and 27 decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AVR architecture the registers are located at the  first 32 address in data memory space as appears in the following picture.

[image]

the address of the register could be representable in 5 bits in the instruction opcode to know exactly where is the 5 bit in the opcode, you have to look at [AVR instruction set Manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf) and see every instruction binary

for example if you look at the **page 115**  in the manual you will see the translation in binary for `LDi`  instruction which is limit you to only access the upper 16 register (from r16 to r31)  the 16 is represented only in the 4 bit, so it appears in the third  Nibble as litter d (d abbreviation for "destination register") **Note: if dddd bits take one value from 0000 to 1111 this will map from r16 to r31**

---

> I cannot figure out which registers are supposed to be r10 and r20

let us manually translation this code `ClR R10`  to opcode to figure out the answer

in the manual (page 71) you will find that the `ClR` is Just `EOR` (Exclusive OR) which mean

```
clr R10
; is same opcode as 
EOR R10,R10
```

now try to found `EOR` translation instead of `ClR`, in manual (Page 91) you will found the following

```
EOR Rd,Rr
;will translat to 
;0010 01rd dddd rrrr
```

now replace `Rd`and`Rr` with `r10` (`r10` in binary will be 01010)
so the output will be

```
;be carful in bits location
;the bits are mixed
0010 01rd dddd rrrr  
0010 0100 1010 1010
```

this is the translate of `CLR R10`

now try to translate `ROR r20` by yourself (hint : `ROR` in page 145)

---

> What I can figure out is, at least I believe, that registers X and Y are $004A and $004B respectively

**this is not correct**, X Y and Z registers are actually pairs of r27:r26, r29:r28 and r31:r30 registers

indirect store instruction `ST` will be translated for different opcode depend on which pairs are selected (x, y, z work as alias for these pairs) and you could see them in **pages 173-177** in the manual

[image]

Comment: The formatting and effort is good (though you should properly format the text of the information in the question rather than posting images of text). StackOverflow allows markdown to do that. Keep that in mind for your next answer. Here, regardless, it is worthy of a vote.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I will put that in my consideration next answer, thanks for support ❤️